# Indenting at the beginning of the document is illegal in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

**This is my controller file**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("order_by DESC")
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end



private

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
end
end
```

**This is my index.html.haml**

`- @posts.each do |post|
     %h2= post.title
      %p = time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)`

*When i run boot the server it is showing 'Indenting at the beginning of the document is illegal' in this code(- @posts.each do |post|) *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Delete white spaces between code and start of line and you'll be good.

2) You have inconsistent indenting. Stick to one amount of space within whole file: it could be 1 space, 2 spaces, 1 tab etc..

Comment: The indentation *amount* isn't relevant, only that it's consistent, no? E.g., you can use four spaces, one tab, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton in theory yes, never used other then 2 spaces, but indeed! thx for pointing out!